# PHP - creating new array value based on explode name in the original array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with this format:

```
$components = [
    [
        'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID',
        'cas'    => '123',
        'einecs' => '321'
    ],
    [
        'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID/DIMETHY- LAMINOHYDROXY- PROPYL DIETHYLENE- TRIAMINE COPOLYMER',
        'cas'    => '456',
        'einecs' => '654'
    ]
]
```

I need to find each `name` which has a `/` character, break it and create a new entry in the **$components** array with **cas** and **einecs** being empty string.

Also the first part of the name will have `cas` and `einecs` values from the original entry.

Expected array:

```
$components = [
        [
            'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID',
            'cas'    => '123',
            'einecs' => '321'
        ],
        [
            'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID',
            'cas'    => '456',
            'einecs' => '654'
        ],[
            'name'   => 'DIMETHY- LAMINOHYDROXY- PROPYL DIETHYLENE- TRIAMINE COPOLYMER',
            'cas'    => '',
            'einecs' => ''
        ]
    ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I need to insert all the components in the db. In this case name can have multiple components, and I need them all.

Comment: I think what he is asking is for you to produce what you expect the example array to look like so that we can compare.  It's currently a little bit unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: base on your given array, give us your expected array.

Comment: Expected result added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite crude I admit and it doesn't account for multiple `/` characters in a value but it does return the result expected.

```
        foreach( $components as $index=> $arr ){
            foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){
                if( $key=='name' && strstr( $value, '/' ) ){
                    list($pre,$post)=explode('/',$value);
                    $components[$index][$key]=$pre;
                    $components[]=array('name'=>$post,'cas'=>'','einecs'=>'');
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$components = [
    [
        'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID',
        'cas'    => '123',
        'einecs' => '321'
    ],
    [
        'name'   => 'ADIPIC ACID/DIMETHY- LAMINOHYDROXY- PROPYL DIETHYLENE- TRIAMINE COPOLYMER',
        'cas'    => '456',
        'einecs' => '654'
    ]
];

$new = [];

foreach ($components as &$component) {
    if ($items = explode('/', $component['name'])) {
        $component['name'] = array_shift($items);
        $new = array_merge($new, $items);
    }
}

foreach ($new as $item) {
    $components[] = ['name' => $item, 'cas' => '', 'einecs' => ''];
}

var_dump($components);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($components as $component)
{
   if(strpos($component["name"],"/") !== false){
      $temp = explode("/",$component["name"]);
      $components[] = new array("name"=>$temp[1], "cas"=>"", "einecs"=>"");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this where I use the `explode` function using the '/' character on the name of each component. Then I'd create a new array of all the new components taking the values of the component being evaluated.

```
$newComponents = array();
foreach($components as $component) {
  foreach(explode('/', $component['name']) as $newComponentName) {
    $newComponents[] = array('name'   =>$newComponentName, 
                             'cas'    => $component['cas'],
                             'einecs' => $component['einecs']);
  }
}
```